# How to initialize unexported structure from another package

Tags: go

I have an unexported Go struct in some package. And I need to initialize and pass it to some func from main package (for testing purposes). How can I initialize this unexported struct? Maybe there are some options with reflect?

Comment: If it's unexported, it's because the package author doesn't want you to use / initialize it from the outside.

Comment: Sure, but  as I noticed I should do it in test purposes without updating of current implementation.

Comment: You could theoretically do it using reflect if there's an exported func in that package that returns an instance of the struct. You can use that to reflect the type, and then create a new instance. Otherwise, no, you cannot.

Comment: *"How can I initialize this unexported struct?"* -- You can't. *"Maybe there are some options with reflect?"* -- Nope.

Comment: This looks very much like an XY problem. Can you state your actual goal, with code examples? Then we can provide a much more appropriate answer.

Comment: @Adrian: while possible, the fields of the internal type must be exported allowing them to be set, and there need to be an entry point in the package which accepts an interface since you cannot assert the unexported type, making it very unlikely to ever work without designing package to be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, the correct way is to vendor the code. I don't mean vendor in the sense of `go mod vendor` (although that might work), but just copying the code from wherever it is online, and moving it into your own package.

If the function in question is in your own package, then it doesn't matter if it's exported or not. This is not ideal solution, especially if the function is heavily ingrained in the original source, but might work for you. As others noted, without some `reflect` hacks, it's not really possible to do what you're asking in the original question. If someone didn't export a function, it's because they don't want you doing what you're trying to do.